# jQuery parent animate second click (close/roll back) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem getting a function with animate to work on the second/closing click. It works on the first click though... Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="about">
  <div id="aboutbtn-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  <div id="aboutbtn">About me</div>
  <div class="social-icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/43x43"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/43x43"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#about {
  background: #336699;
  height: 561px;
  width: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right:-285px;
}

#aboutbtn {
  background: #336699;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 85px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -85px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block !important;
}

#aboutbtn-content {
  float: left;
  padding: 35px 30px;
}

.social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  left: -63px;
  top: 140px;
}

.social-icons img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#aboutbtn").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        right: '-280px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        right: '0px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
});
});
```

I have made a [jsfiddle you can see by clicking here](http://jsfiddle.net/mediabird/93v3qayh/1/).

I got inspiration [from this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/3/), only difference is I changed it from toggle to click.

I'm not the sharpest JS-coder, so please bear with me :D. I'll appreciate any answer!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simplified method without the extra overhead of adding classes to dom elements then querying dom elements over and over again.

Basically we set a variable `open` to `false`, on click check to see if `open` is `false`, if so then set `open` to `true` (because its open now) then open it, if not then set `open` to `false` and close it

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/93v3qayh/10/))

```js
var open = false;
$("#aboutbtn").click(function () {
    if(!open) $(this).parent().animate({ right: '0px'}, 500);
    else $(this).parent().animate({ right: '-285px'}, 500);
    open = !open ? true : false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one maybe.

Since you had issues with animations stacking, this bunch of code just make sure the div is at the right position to allow the opening or the closing animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdasilva/93v3qayh/9/

```
$("#aboutbtn").click(function () {
    var parentPos = $(this).parent().css('right').split('px')[0];
    var targetPos = (parentPos == 0 ? -280 : 0);
    $(this).parent().animate({right:targetPos}, 500);
});
```

I've shortened the code and provided a jsfiddle link with my last edit. You don't need all those options settings for your "animate" function. 
By the way, i'm new to this site and i don't know why i've been downvoted so fast. If the "downvoter" could tell me why maybe i could learn and improve my answers...